# HTML - What kind of layout tags should I use to do a layout

Tags: html, css

I'm doing a layout for an account page.  And I'm thinking my code looks horrible because I am trying to avoid using tables.  Here is a screen shot of what I want to get:
[image]

Right now, I'm using something like this (see jsfiddle): http://jsfiddle.net/uaUtq/7/

Here it is for quick review:

```
<ul class="info_list">
    <li>
        <label>First name</label>
        <div><input type="text" /></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>Email</label>
        <div>
            <p>john@gmail.com (Default)</p>
            <input type="text"/></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label></label>
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" />Tickbox
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>​
```

It feels ugly and complicated. What way would you advise to do it?

Thanks

Comment: Just for my information, why do you want to avoid using tables?

Comment: I think you should change your style of indenting the markup first.

Comment: @AmitBhargava - I keep reading everywhere, that I should avoid using tables for layout purposes.  I would be happy to use tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you should use div instead of li
like this

```
<div>
    <div class="label">First Name</div>
    <div class="element"><input type="text"/></div>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="label">Email</div>
    <div class="element"><input type="text"/></div>
</div>
```

and write CSS class for label and control to proper alignment i.e. margin, padding, float, etc.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with using an unordered list for what you're doing. Other options you could think about are just using a form, then just wrapping your label-input pairings in divs for layout purposes:

```
<form>
  <div>
    <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="firstName" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="text" id="email" />
  </div>
// etc.
</form>
```

Comment: +1 for using labels that are explicitly associated with the inputs.

Comment: i would recommend `<p>` tag instead of `<div>` for the fact that it's more semantic. anyways harm done using `<div>`!! Please +1 if you like the idea.

Comment: <p> tag wouldn't add any semantic value so it's no more appropriate than a div in this case

Answer (score 2):

Don't mess with too many tags.

Just use `<div>...</div>` and **leave the styling part to CSS**

*(that's its original purpose anyway : to separate "content" from "design")*...

Answer (score -1):

You should use a table. A table is the only way to make the columns aligned so that the first column occupies just the width it needs (the width of the longest label). Any other approach forces you to make a guess on the width, and the results will inevitably vary, and the code will not be robust (the width needs to be adjusted whenever the length of the longest label changes).

(This is a repeating question, and you’ll find many versions of it at StackOverflow, with varying answers. The issue is very simple once you stop listening to ideological arguments that are not backed up with facts.)

Comment: A table is not the only way to align the columns like that without specifying a width: http://jsfiddle.net/n9SgC/

Comment: In addition to kinakuta's above jsfiddle, you could float containing divs instead of using display: inline-block to accomplish the same thing (and be IE7 compatible.) No need for tables which have a purpose of their own outside of old layout techniques.

Comment: kinakuta’s code does not work on IE 7 or even on IE 8. And floats come with all kinds of problems and quirks, and there is nothing natural in using them to avoid using a table for tabular material like an array of form fields and their legends.

Comment: The code works fine on IE8. Nothing wrong with using floats either if you have to support IE7 and floats can have issues if you don't understand how to work around IE7's many issues. Form fields are not tabular material.